# Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"

Tags: ruby, windows

I just uninstalled my older versions of Ruby, removed all of my gems
(including Rails), and installed Ruby 2.0. In other words, a totally clean re-install. Upon starting IRB, I received this message:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
```

Note: I'm on a Windows machine.

What does this message mean?

Comment: What are the contents of your `~/.irbrc` file?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but where can I locate this file?

Comment: @CodeGnome Notice that @effbot is on a Windows machine. From what I can see, Windows does not have an `.irbrc` by default.

Comment: The `warn` you are getting is coming from the file "Ruby200\lib\ruby\2.0.0\dl.rb". I get it as well when I start up either `irb` or `pry`.

Comment: If you have an `.irbrc` file, it'll be located in your user directory. So, `C:\Users\{username}` on Windows Vista and above and `C:\Documents and Settings\{username}` on XP.

Comment: This is not related to .irbrc, this is in requiring irb. Please see the complete answer below

Comment: This is such a badly written message. What's DL? What's Fiddle? Why should I change? How can I change?

Comment: upgrading from ruby 2.1.5 to 2.3.0 and the message is now gone for me on Windows.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

The message you received is common when you have **`ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24)`** on top of **Windows**.

The message "`DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle`" **is not an error; it's only a warning**.

The source is the [Deprecation notice for DL](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext/dl/lib) introduced some time ago in `dl.rb` ( see [revisions/37910](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/37910/entry/ext/dl/lib/dl.rb) ).

On Windows the `lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/readline.rb` file still requires `dl.rb` so the **warning message** comes out when you `require 'irb'` ( because irb requires `'readline'` ) or when anything else wants to `require 'readline'`.

You can open `readline.rb` with your favorite text editor and look up the code ( near line 4369 ):

```
    if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.1'
      require 'Win32API'
    else
      require 'dl'
      class Win32API
        DLL = {}
```

We can always hope for an improvement to work out this deprecation in future releases of [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).

EDIT:
For those wanting to go deeper about **Fiddle** vs **DL**, let it be said that their purpose is to dynamically link external libraries with Ruby; you can read on the ruby-doc website about [DL](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/dl/rdoc/DL.html) or [Fiddle](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html).

Comment: @webRat Just re-edit the post; I agree with you, the rbrealine.rb was introduced by a wrong (I suppose) Edit by community. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: All this sounds so unsatisfactory.  Anyway, taking note of the comment below from Msangle, "What is fiddle?"

Comment: Using `Ruby 2.0.x`, I had an error message in addition to warning, `DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle.` I installed `Ruby 1.9` and no longer have this error. Thanks to this site - https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1080-why-all-rhc-commands-on-windows-result-in-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle-error.

Comment: DL, Fiddle... what are these things at all?

Comment: @Paul, at the last two lines of the answer there are two link that maybe you have not seen: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html , http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/dl/rdoc/DL.html

Comment: On my Windows machine, I located this files `rbreadline.rb` and `readline.rb` at `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.1.0\ `. I changed the line from `require 'dl'` to `require 'fiddle'`. No more warnings.

Comment: This doesn't work as there are dependencies down the line, I'm afraid, @Blairg23

Comment: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\2.1.0 line 8

Answer (score 73):

You may want to comment out the `DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle` warning at

```
C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\2.0.0\dl.rb
```

since it’s annoying and you are not the irb/pry or some other gems code owner

Comment: If you are getting this error when running `vagrant up` on Windows, this file can be found at `C:\vagrant\embedded\lib\ruby\2.0.0dl.rb`.

Comment: Thanks @syj, mine was located at `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\lib\ruby\2.0.0\dl.rb`

Comment: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\2.1.0\dl.rb line 8

Answer (score 3):

I got this resolution at [openshift.com](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202187604-Why-all-rhc-commands-on-windows-result-in-DL-is-deprecated-please-use-Fiddle-error-).

Resolution:

> This error occurs only on Windows machine with Ruby 2.0.0 version.
>   Until we officially support Ruby 2.0 please downgrade to Ruby 1.9.
>
> On Windows, you can install Ruby 1.9.3 alongside 2.0. Change your
>   %PATH% to `c:\ruby193\` or whatever directory you installed to prior
>   to installing the gem.

Comment: Could you additionally give a link to the solution on openshift.com?

Comment: Is there any plan to officially support ruby 2.0 in the very near future?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt The solution is now referenced. See my edit above.

Answer (score 3):

The message "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" is not an error; it's only a warning.
Solution:
You can ignore this in 3 simple steps.
Step 1. Goto C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\2.1.0
Step 2. Then find dl.rb and open the file with any online editors like   Aptana,sublime text etc
Step 3.  Comment the line 8 with '#' ie # warn "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" .
That's it, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this myself when I wanted to make a thor command under Windows.

To avoid having that message output everytime I ran my thor application I temporarily muted warnings while loading thor:

```
begin
  original_verbose = $VERBOSE
  $VERBOSE = nil
  require "thor"
ensure
  $VERBOSE = original_verbose
end
```

That saved me from having to edit third party source files.

Comment: cool solution, it does not require changes in other people's code.