# Ruby on rails error after cloning a project from github and trying to run the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on rails.
I just installed the railsinstaller 3.0.3 for windows from the railsinstaller.org website.

It has rails version : 4.0.2 
       ruby version : 2.0

I also did a

**bundle install**

I cloned a project from github and when I try  to run commands

`rake db:create.` or

```
rails s
```

It give me the following error :

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
For a better pry experience, please use ansicon: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon.
```

Does anyone know what it means ? and how to resolve it ?

Comment: Are you sure is giving you an error and not just a warning? Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a warning that appears on Windows installs of Ruby 2. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle) on the subject.