# DL is deprecated, please use fiddle message on installing Bourbon and Neat

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

i just installed SASS version  `3.3.5 maple` and now using command line I installed  bourbon using `gem install bourbon` which installed  `bourbon 3.1.8` and also installed neat which is `ver 1.6.0`
Now i went to my blank folder and run this

```
command `bourbon install`
DL is deprecated,please use fiddle.
```

Although it installs the folders it gives further errors on compilation. Please tell me what to do.
thanks.

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 1):

These warning have been reported before on Windows: [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)

The Sass warnings are due to the fact that Bourbon 3.1.8 is still not fully-optimized for Sass 3.3.5, and thus you get the deprecation warnings. This should be fixed in Bourbon 4.0.

Comment: I tried using scout for compilation and it also gave errors