# How to run ScrAPI with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, web-scraping

I'm trying to run scrapi with `rails` with this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'scrapi'
require 'tidy'

scraper = Scraper.define do
    process "title", :page_name => :text
    result :page_name
end

uri = URI.parse("http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi")
p scraper.scrape(uri)
```

but I get the following error:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy/tidybuf.rb:5:in `<class:Tidybuf>': uninitialized constant DL::Importable (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy/tidybuf.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy.rb:25:in `<module:Tidy>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from scrapitest.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

has anybody got an idea why is that and what could I do to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: The message you received is common on  `ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24)` on top of `Windows`, Are you in these environments, Please looks at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle) post.

Comment: @saurabh I'm in `Linux` not `Windows`

Answer (score 0):

Try http://github.com/libc/tidy_ffi instead. It seems `tidy` gem is not mantained anymore.