# Rails Generate Controller gives me load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, command-prompt

I try to generate a controller but it gives me this error. I can't find where in my files what caused this error so help would be much appreciated. I am running Ruby '2.0.0' and rails '4.2.0.beta2' if that helps at all. PLEASE help! Thanks

I don't undestand WHY this post is getting marked as a duplicate. My question has nothing to do with that other question. Plus, I am asking what to do to fix it, and as far as I read, I didn't even see a fix to that error. PLEASE HELP!

```
c:\Users\NAME\workspace\sample_app>rails generate controller StaticPages home help

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in
`require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/s
lave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.r
b:13:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.r
b:13:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.r
b:1:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.r
b:1:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:i
n `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `requ
ire'
from c:/Users/Devin Miller/workspace/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (
required)>'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate_or_destroy'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands/c
ommands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/commands.r
b:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB error: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle), that message is only a warning, not an error. Perhaps an error lies somewhere else? Study the error trace message and hopefully you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problems is the Rails 4.2.0.beta depends on the `pty` gem and is unable to find it:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- pty
```

The reason is that the `pty` gem is not available on Windows. Hopefully that gets fixed before Rails 4.2 is released. At the moment you can fix this problem by removing the `web-console` gem from your `Gemfile`:

```
# Gemfile
# gem 'web-console'
```

Run `bundle install` after removing that gem.

---

To fix the problem that `no source of timezone data could be found (TZinfo::DataSourceNotFound)` please add the following line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

And then try again:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rails generate controller StaticPages home help
```