# railstutorial rake aborted LoadError: cannot load such file -- pty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm learning Ruby on rails, and doing what I thought was the smart thing by going through the railstutorial guide.  Everything seemed fine, until it came time to work on the database at the beginning of chapter two, where I received a LoadError message and the rake was aborted when creating the sqlite db table.

Here is the complete output when I type in:

bundle exec rake db:migrate

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- pty
f:/web/rails_workspace/toy_app/config/application.rb:7:in '<top (required)>'
f:/web/rails_workspace/toy_app/config/Rakefile:4:in 'require'
f:/web/rails_workspace/toy_app/config/Rakefile:4:in '<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

if you really need the full trace, I will add it.

I've looked around here, and although I've found similar issues, nothing quite matches.

The Gemfile is straight copy from the tutorial (railstutorial.org) and worked fine for creating the project and deploying, with Hello World appearing as expected.  It is only when I get to the database that any error comes up, and it's a stopper.

I really don't think the DL is the issue, but I'm learning.

Comment: Have you tried `bundle install` before the `rake db:reset`?

Comment: What's on line # 7 of config/application.rb ? that's the line throwing the error. Best to include the full content of the file by editing the question.

Comment: Also, I describe how to get a minimal db setup working in the reproduction steps in [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319575/how-can-i-force-the-rails-sql-cache-to-clear), which may help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26666930/429758 should be helpful.