# Terminal window is not accepting commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used PHP for quite sometime now. But I want to be a ROR developer. I would love to know of the process to create a website in Ruby. Well !!! I am getting an error "DL is deprecated please use Fiddle" and the terminal window is not accepting any command. Can anyone please tell how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to RoR and SO, make sure you are clear with your doubts.

Comment: Just google the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle