# Stuck installing Rails: rails s and bundle exec rails server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, ide

I am using Windows 7, Ruby 2.2.1, and Rails 4.2.0.
I get the following error after running `rails s` or `bundle exec rails server`:

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `<module:Helper>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.8.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/David/Documents/testapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'        
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I have also run `gem list`, and these gems are installed. Is it an issue with certain gem versions?

Also, it's 64-bit Windows; could it be in issue with that? I installed the 32 bit, so it should be compatible, right? I will try to uninstall and re-install everything with the 64-bit version of the DevKit and Ruby.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to install the correct dll for nokogiri.  When i first started i used windows for about 6 months before moving to linux for ruby development.  It is noticeably faster and you don't run into as much weirdness as in windows.  I recommend installing a virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 on it.

Comment: I may just find an old HDD somewhere install Ubuntu onto it. looks like windows isn't the way to go.

Comment: You will save yourself alot of heartache.  I experience a lot of pain before i spent the time to switch and wish i had not waited that long.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue just today. I tried to do a new installation of ruby and rails today and I couldn't get "rails server" to work for the exact same reason.

In order to get this to work, you need to run
    `gem install nokogiri --platform="ruby"`
but this fails on Windows because nokogiri doesn't compile properly on Windows.

It's supposed to work with the pre-compiled binary installation that RubyGems pulls down, but I think there's a bug somewhere in RubyGems or nokogiri that's causing this to not work right now, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm pretty much installing to learn Ruby. I'm going to try and older version for Ruby, but if its the Gems I don't see how I will get around this. It seems its not just nokogiri.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so I rolled back to 2.0.0. and it worked. You get "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" which I found here, [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle), is just a warning. Still switching to Ubuntu soon.