# DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

Tags: ruby, windows

I just installed a ruby 2.2.1 and got this warning when I ran bundle install:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
```

I came to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601984/587959) and found the code they pointed out in rbreadline.rb line 4367.

```
if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9.1'
      require 'Win32API'
    else
      require 'dl'
      class Win32API
        DLL = {}
        TYPEMAP = {"0" => DL::TYPE_VOID, "S" => DL::TYPE_VOIDP, "I" => DL::TYPE_LONG}
```

I then added the `require 'irb'` line next to the `require 'dl'` line as they suggested but this did not remove the warning for me. I realize this may only be a warning but I do not want to comment out the message only to have other problems spring up latter. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a broken version of RubyInstaller that was distributed for about 5 hours.

There were only about 800 downloads of it before someone caught it, but it appears that you are running one of those downloads.

Sorry about that.

Check out [the mailing list announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyinstaller/8twRyeYge7A/MEjvB4rzqXkJ) for more details.

The fix is to *re-install* using the fixed distribution.

Comment: Yeah, the crash only manifests with an interactive shell, like `irb`, but a broken release is broken.