# Redmine BitNami 'DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle'

Tags: redmine, bitnami

(This question is not duplicated, already asked question is for Ruby)

Actually I am trying to install Redmin on windows.
to achieve this I am using Bitnami, and following these installation instructions
[easyredmine](http://www.easyredmine.com/installation-of-bitnami-redmine-on-windows)
I have reached to step 4 where I have to run bundle command but I am getting error

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

Now how can I override this and what I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)

Comment: Redmine is written in Ruby and the source of the issue is Ruby itself. Why do you think that Redmine is any special here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ruby two versions, 1.9 and later install 2.0. I was assuming I am using 2.0 but when I check I was using 1.9 so 2.0 solve my problem.
Thanks you all