# how to solve" DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" Rails 4.1.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rubygems

[image: screenshoot my cmd]

i install ruby on rails package, and check the version. when i check rails version it show DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle.
How to solve DL is deprecated, Please use Fiddle ?
i am using Windows 8.1 
thanks before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Ruby 2.0.0 deprecated DL to move towards fiddle movement, your best answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601984/4316935) to get rid of the warning message that I also encountered a while ago. Good luck!