# Why "login: nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

**cart.rb**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :login

  has_one :cart

end
```

**when I create a user in rails console, message:**

```
E:\work\my_store>rails c
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
irb(main):001:0> user1 = User.new(login: "user1")
=> #<User id: nil, login: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0>
```

**Why not login assigned value " login: "user1" " ?**
**Help me to solve this**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle

Comment: put this `attr_accessible :login` below `attr_accesor`  and try to create the record.

Comment: `login` is part of your user table attributes? @amit `attr_accessible` is not available anymore in rails 4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/17371364/895789