# Error related to missing directory/file for bundle in Windows on creating new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**UPDATE:**
It seems ruby/rails did not like the fact that path of ruby installation has spaces (e.g: `Program Files (x86)`).  I re-installed ruby in "E:\ruby" and things seems to work fine now.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I am trying to follow rails guide and create a new rails app using "rails new blog" command.

However, I am getting weird error on my windows m/c.  See the trace below:

```
E:\rails>rails new blog
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:321:in ``': No such file or directory - ""E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200
-x64/bin/ruby.exe"" "E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/bin/bundle" install (Errno::ENOENT)
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:321:in `block in bundle_command'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:245:in `block in with_clean_env'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:232:in `with_original_env'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:238:in `with_clean_env'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:320:in `bundle_command'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:335:in `run_bundle'
        from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        from E:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby200-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Ruby Version

```
E:\rails>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]
```

Gem list

```
E:\rails>gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.2)
actionpack (4.2.2)
actionview (4.2.2)
activejob (4.2.2)
activemodel (4.2.2)
activerecord (4.2.2)
activesupport (4.2.2)
arel (6.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.4, 1.8.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.5)
i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.11)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
loofah (2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.7.0, 4.3.2)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2 x64-mingw32)
power_assert (0.2.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.2)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.2)
rake (10.4.2, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.2.0, 4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.8, 2.4.6)
sprockets (3.2.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.1)
test-unit (3.1.2, 2.0.0.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)

Comment: @Pavan I read the link you shared - it asks me to comment out the line that prints "DL is deprecated..." line.  That does not seem to fix the issue though