# Ruby on Rails: How do I solve this error when running "Bundle Install"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I've just downloaded Rails Installer (Rails 4.1.8) on my windows machine, and when I try to run `bundle install` I get the following error:

`C:\Sites\BettingSite>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...`

`Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2'' succeeds before bundling.`

I also had an error "DL is deprecated please use fiddle" but I prevented this from appearing by following the second answer down on the following StackOverFlow question: [Ruby 2.0.0p0 IRB warning: "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)

Can someone please tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: Does this link help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error

Comment: Yes there was an answer on there that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks too @Stephane J's link this has been solved.

The problem was that I needed to change:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

In the Gemfile, as was recommended on this link: [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)