# Console not loading server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have Ruby on Rails installed and I can run the server fine using `rails server`, but when I use `rails console` to start the console it doesn't load properly.

I guess it may an issue with WEBrick but that loads in the server?!

Here is a screenshot showing that the server works as expected:
[image: Working rails server]

And here is one of the failed console:
[image: Failed rails console]

I'm running "Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit" with Ruby 2.0.0p598 and Rails 4.2.2.

Comment: first i cannot see any error, just a warning. second this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle is similar to your case. i hope this will help you.:)

Comment: @Athar the issue is that it doesn't load the WEBrick server, but cheers for that link.

Comment: im sorry can you share in question what happens when you hit `localhost:3000` in browser as that will help us finding the issue. currently what im seeing from the image. it is showing that Webrick is running on rails s with pid 6068. please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Running the console doesn't load the web server. It just brings up an irb session with your rails environment loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rails console` isn't supposed to run the server. It's the console, and you just mess with it, typing stuff inside and getting replies from it via on-screen text messages.

Everything's working fine, you may continue venturing into the mysterious and rewarding world of Ruby on Rails development.

Comment: Ahh, I was told it loaded the server too! Sorry for time wasting, cheers for the advice!