# Error trying to run redmine on thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, thin

I am trying to run Redmine on a Windows server.  The server already has IIS running on it so I have installed Apache on ports 8080 and 449.  I am following the tutorial here:

https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall
and
https://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/32693

However when I try to run "thin start -e production -p 3000" I get the following long message:

```
C:\Redmine>thin start -e production -p 3000
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:103: war
ning: epoll is not supported on this platform
Using rack adapter
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb fil
es accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test enviro
nment)
  * production - set it to true

C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'pro
duction bundle exec rails c' database is not configured. Available: ["production
", "development", "test"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'

        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_re
cord/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `bloc
k in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
        from C:/Redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <
top (required)>'
        from C:/Redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
        from C:/Redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (requi
red)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.
rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_s
upport/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.
rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.
rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.
rb:615:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.
rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_
strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_
strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_c
omponent_from'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_co
nnected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_c
omponent_from'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_co
nnected_component'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_c
omponent'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/applica
tion.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'
        from C:/Redmine/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:5
5:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:5
5:in `initialize'
        from C:/Redmine/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from C:/Redmine/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/load
er.rb:33:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/load
er.rb:33:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/rack/adapter/load
er.rb:42:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/
controller.rb:170:in `load_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/
controller.rb:74:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:20
0:in `run_command'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:15
6:in `run!'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thin-1.6.4/bin/thin:6:in `<top (
required)>'
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/thin:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby21/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried editing the files config/environments/***.rb, but development and test files were already set to false and production already set to true.

I also tried connecting with different users in the database.yml file, but still get this error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Log message is saying,your database is not configured for production environment. Have you configured your production database?

Comment: Pardon my ignroance but configured how?  The tables all exist in the mysql database.  When I installed this on another computer I didn't need to take any special steps other than specifying the username and password in the database.yml.  I'm not sure why this machine is behaving differently :(

Comment: OK I ran that and the output was just "DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle" then back to the command prompt.

Comment: I think, you are using windows environment . Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-warning-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle

Comment: Yes I know - it's not an error.  But when I try to run "thin start -e production -p 3000" I still get the error I mentioned in my question...

Comment: First you need to check if your production database is configured or not.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do this!!  What do you mean by configured?  How can I check?

Comment: when you set the development environment then you simply ran "rake db:create; rake db:migrate" and same you need to set for production environment. "rake db:create -e production; rake db:migration -e production"

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  When I try to run "rake db:create -e production;" I get:     C:\Redmine>rake db:create -e production;
    rake aborted!
    NameError: undefined local variable or method `production' for #<Rake::Applicati
    on:0x27db4b0>
    
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)...  I have no idea what I am doing :(

Comment: try to replece "-e production" to "RAILS_ENV=production" Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thankyou!  Now when I run "rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production" it says "redmine already exists".

Comment: redmine is your database name right?

Comment: Yes that's correct :)